# Compacting vertical space between two overlapping linear splines

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, spline

I have two or more linear splines - similar to 1D parameters, but really 2d, with splines having beginning and end points and the ability for multiple splines to exist in the same space.

```````````
`\___/````\_____/\/`````\


___/``````````\_______/`````
```````````

How can I go about compacting the space as much as possible, such that the lines never cross

```````````
`\___/````\_____/\/`````\
___/``````````\_______/`````
```````````

Comment: Do you mean something more elaborate than "find the lowest point of A and the highest point of B, and ensure the two don't overlap"?

Comment: Find all "interesting" X coordinates (for 2 splines, basically, X coordinates of the vertices of either spline). For each X coordinate, compute Y of the first and the second spline, and find their difference. Find the minimum over all such differences. You can lift the second spline by any amount less than this minimum.

Comment: n.m.  That answers my question.  If you post it as an answer I will mark it correct.